# Get the Underlying data in a measure to show in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following data and with amazing help of Sam Nseir I sailed through a lot of problems -

| UniqueID | OrderDate | Shipping Date | Delivery Date | Division | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A174 | 8/18/2022 13:14 |  |  | AZ | AZ1 |
| A196 | 11/17/2022 19:33 | 21-Sep-23 | 21-Sep-23 | MP | MP1 |
| A197 | 1/11/2023 17:24 | 21-Nov-23 |  | MP | MP1 |
| A179 | 5/30/2023 12:55 | 21-Oct-23 | 21-Oct-23 | WB | WB1 |
| A178 | 6/23/2023 21:19 | 21-Sep-23 |  | WB | WB1 |
| A180 | 6/27/2023 19:16 | 21-Sep-23 | 21-Sep-23 | AZ | AZ1 |
| A195 | 9/21/2023 19:06 | 21-Oct-23 | 21-Oct-23 | AZ | AZ1 |

I want to show the Same table in Table Chart in PowerBI.
But when I select 2023 the Order with ID `A196` doesn't show up since the Active Relationship of the DateTable is with `OrderDate` which makes sense (Also, there are two inactive relationships with Shipping Date and Delivery Date).

How does one go about showing the data that we get in the following measure -

The Date Role table is a simple table with three rows to act as a slicer for selecting OrderDate, Shipping date and Delivery date.

**What I want to do?**

So, if I select Shipping Date I should get all rows with Shipping Date even if they fall out of the current DateTable context but If I select March I should get only the ones that fall in March i.e. 0.

This measure gets the counts of Such Orders -

```
Date Role Count = 
var oRole = CONTAINS('Date Role',  'Date Role'[Role], "OrderDate")
var sRole = CONTAINS('Date Role',  'Date Role'[Role], "Shipping Date")
var dRole = CONTAINS('Date Role',  'Date Role'[Role], "Delivery Date")

var oValues = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT(Data[UniqueID]),
        NOT ISBLANK(Data[UniqueID]) = oRole
    )

var sValues = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT(Data[UniqueID]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(DATETABLE[DATE], Data[Shipping Date],
        NOT ISBLANK(Data[UniqueID]) = sRole
    )

var dValues = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT(Data[UniqueID]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(DATETABLE[DATE],Data[Delivery Date]),
        NOT ISBLANK(Data[UniqueID]) = dRole
    )

RETURN COUNTROWS( DISTINCT( UNION( oValues, sValues, dValues ) )
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are wanting. In your Table visual, add the `Date Role Count` measure to it, and then test it. Is that what you are after?

Comment: No, I want to show the entire Table (as shown) in the table Viz. but when I select 2023 in the Slicer (Made on `DateTable[Date]` Joined to `OrderDate`) and Select `Delivery Date` in the `Date Role` slicer it filters out the rows that were created in 2022 but since they were delivered in 2023. I want to include the table to show that entry.

Comment: Let me know if you've any follow up questions.

Comment: What am I missing? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5siU2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `OrderDate` is Date/Time, you can't use this for your relationship (because the Time won't match. So you will need to create a new column of `OrderDate` that is just the Date.

Create a new Calculated Column with:

```
Date = DATEVAULE( [OrderDate] )
```

Then update the Active relationship to use `Date` instead of `OrderDate`.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to switch active relationships as well? If I select OrderDate It shouldn't show up, if it's 2023. Similarly for the Delivery Date, only 4 rows should appear (if 2023 is selected)?

Comment: It doesn't show: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebwAf.png - when `Role` slicer has no selection, then any date in the three columns that are in 2023 will show, when you select `OrderDate` then just the column etc...

Comment: One more question, is there a way to show the columns in Table Viz. the rows that are currently in the `Date Role Count` measure?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that what it's doing at the moment? Share an annotated snip or similar. Do you mean to not show the `Date Role Count` column?

Comment: Ok, Understood what I was doing wrong. It's mandatory to have `Date Role Count` as a Column in the table for it to include the 2022 entry. Is there a way to achieve the same without adding it as a column in the table?

Comment: Select the table visual, then go to the Filter pane, and under `Filters on this visual`, set the filter for `Date Role Count` to `is not blank`. Then remove the measure from visual columns.

Comment: Just tried it's removing the entry with 2022 but when I add the measure as 
a column it comes back - https://imgur.com/a/g3MOfEk

Comment: The same Visual when I add the measure back - https://imgur.com/a/BoHbImt

Comment: My bad, the measure will need to stay in the column. You can resize the column to hide it as much as you can.

Comment: There is a way to do it without having it in the matrix. Set the Active relationship to be InActive, then update the measure to include `USERELATIONSHIP(DATETABLE[DATE], Data[Date]),` for the `var oValues` (like the other two). BUT you will lose the ability to slice/filter the table via the Date table without the measure.

Comment: Hey Sam! I was trying out RLS using `USERPRINCIPALNAME()` but PowerBI threw the following error - `The UseRelationship() and CrossFilter() functions may not be used when querying "Col" because it is constrained by row-level security defined on 'SEARCH' or related tables.` Seems like this model will fail if we go on to introduce RLS, right?